# How does Rambam decide what defines a Mitzvah?

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, rambam

Rambam in [Sefer Hamitzvos](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.1?lang=he) lists 14 rules that guided him in writing his Sefer Hamitzvos. Practically all of them focus on what does not consitute a Mitzvah Deoraytah:

> השרש הראשון **שאין ראוי למנות** בכלל הזה המצות שהם מדרבנן
>
> השרש השני **שאין ראוי למנות** כל מה שלמדין באחת משלש עשרה מדות שהתורה נדרשת בהן או ברבוי:
>
> השרש השלישי **שאין ראוי למנות** מצות שאין נוהגות לדורות:
>
> השרש הרביעי **שאין ראוי למנות** הצוויין הכוללים כל התורה:
>
> השרש החמישי **שאין ראוי למנות** טעם המצוה מצוה בפני עצמה:
>
> השרש הששי שהמצוה שיהיה בה עשה ולא תעשה, ראוי שימנה עשה שבה עם מצות עשה ולא תעשה שבה עם מצות לא תעשה:
>
> השרש השביעי **שאין ראוי למנות** דקדוקי משפטי התורה:
>
> השרש השמיני **שאין ראוי למנות** שלילות החיוב עם האזהרה:
>
> השרש התשיעי **שאין ראוי למנות** הלאוין והעשה, אבל הדברים המוזהר מהן והמצווה בהם:
>
> השרש העשירי **שאין ראוי למנות** ההקדמות שהן לתכלית אחת מן התכליות:
>
> השרש האחד עשר **שאין ראוי למנות** חלקי המצוה בפרט חלק חלק בפ"ע כשיהיה המקובץ מהם מצוה אחת:
>
> השרש השנים עשר **שאין ראוי למנות** חלקי מלאכה מן המלאכות שבא הצווי בעשייתם כל חלק וחלק בפני עצמו:
>
> השרש השלשה עשר **שהמצות לא ירבה מספרם** כמספר הימים שתתחייב בהן המצוה ההיא:
>
> השרש הארבעה עשר **שאין ראוי למנות** העמדת הגדרים*[*העונשים] במצות עשה:

How does Rambam decides that a verse in the Torah constitue a Mitzvah in a positive way?

Comment: I presume if there's a verse which says to do/not do something, and it meets these 14 criteria, it makes the list. Look at any one of his 613 mitzvos. He brings a verse for each one, as his proof that it's a mitzvah. There are a couple of exceptions where there's no explicit verse, and the Rambam himself explains why it makes the list anyways (ex: Chazal said it's a mitzvah, the Torah gives a prohibition, etc.)

Comment: @robev I liked your approach, you're saying: 1. list all the Do's and Don'ts 2. sort out all the 14 rules 3. You'll be present with exactly 613 Mitzvos left. Empirically it is far from being truth, many Mitzvos are not based on commandments, like ונקדשתי בתוך בני ישראל is not a command. Some contradict the 14 rules, like not having sex with one's daughter is not written in the Torah.

Comment: Your last point is what I mentioned. An exception that the Rambam himself addresses. ונקדשתי is Hashem saying He shall be sanctified. Pretty implicit that we have to make that happen. A good question on my approach are the "concept" mitzvos, like the 12-odd Tuma mitzvos